# Yanked subdependency - Error [E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `__rt` in `quote`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, amethyst

I'm learning Rust from ["Practical Rust Projects"](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484255988) by Shing Lyu. I'm now trying to build a game following the steps in Chapter 4. I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

After installing Rust and the Amethyst command line, I created a new project via `amethyst new cat_volleyball`. The next step is to run the engine using `cargo run --features=vulkan`
. When I do so, I get the error prompt below. Do you have suggestions on how to fix this?

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `__rt` in `quote`
   --> /home/alberto/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/err-derive-0.1.6/src/lib.rs:145:63
    |
145 | fn display_body(s: &synstructure::Structure) -> Option<quote::__rt::TokenStream> {
    |                                                               ^^^^ could not find `__rt` in `quote`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `err-derive`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** Edit the `Cargo.lock` manually, please check the title below for the proper steps : *How to force cargo to use yanked version of sub-dependency*

---

### Why this happens ?

Because `err-derive-0.1.6` is using `quote-1.0.2` as a dependency and quote is declared like below:

```ini
[dependencies.quote]
version = "1.0.2"
```

It means Cargo will use the latest patch update, so if `quote-1.0.3` is out then cargo will use `1.0.3` instead `1.0.2`. Please check [caret-requirement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#caret-requirements). The problem in here is `quote-1.0.3` breaks the backward compatibility, the part that used by `err-derive-0.1.6` is no longer exists in `quote-1.0.3`.

### How to force cargo to use specific version of sub-dependency

You can fix this issue by forcing the sub-dependency to use compatible version for your dependency.
This command will do it :

```
> cargo update -p quote --precise 1.0.2
```

## How to force cargo to use yanked version of sub-dependency

Looks like `quote-1.0.2` was yanked from crates.io, so command up above will not work because cargo will not be able to find the yanked version on crates.io . Since cargo update modifies the `cargo.lock` we can do it manually. To start clean :

1. Remove `Cargo.lock`
2. Run `cargo update` ( this will generate the latest version of `Cargo.lock` )
3. Edit `Cargo.lock` :

Find the incompatible version of package in cargo.lock which is `quote-1.0.3`, It should look like this:

```ini
[[package]]
name = "quote"
version = "1.0.3"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
dependencies = [
 "proc-macro2 1.0.9 (registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index)",
]
```

then simply change version to the compatible version in our case it is `"1.0.2"`

```ini
[[package]]
name = "quote"
version = "1.0.2"
```

After doing that do not run cargo update again, it will overwrite your changes and you'll not able to compile your project. Please remember this is a workaround for being able to continue the development, there is a reason to yank crates, do not use it in production it is best to wait dependent crates to update itself.

---

**Note :**  In some cases you may get an error after editing `cargo.lock`:

```
error: Found argument 'Cargo.lock' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

@albus_c fixed this by [doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576277/rust-amethyst-error-e0433-failed-to-resolve-could-not-find-rt-in-qu#comment107170379_60576395) :

> A note for posterity: I fixed the issue removing rustc
> (`sudo apt remove rustc`) and reinstalled as recommended on the Rust website,
> `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`
> After that everything worked fine.

Comment: A note for posterity: I fixed the issue removing rustc (`sudo apt remove rustc`) and reinstalled as recommended on the Rust website, `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`. After that everything worked fine.